# Where do I get the configure script for PHP source?

Tags: php, build, autoconf, buildconfig

I am currently trying to build an extension for PHP via PECL.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/bin/pecl install memcached`

I am using OS X and MAMP, so I got this error.

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found

Since MAMP is shipping without any header files for PHP, I had to get them manually.
So I went to here https://github.com/php/php-src/releases/tag/php-5.4.39 and downloaded the source.

I extracted it to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/include/` and renamed the folder `php-5php-src-PHP-5.4.39` folder to `php` and tried change to the folder `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/include/php`.

I tried to run the configuration script with `./configure`.
But it was not found.
I only found an `configure.ln`, which as I was told was for autoconf. So I ran `autoconf`. Autoconf crashed with errors like this:

> configure.in:2: error: possibly undefined macro: dnl

I was confused. I found the script `./buildconf` which told me the following:

> You should not run buildconf in a release package.
>   use buildconf --force to override this check.

I forced it and there we go: a `./configure` script finally existed.

I checked the php.net site for the same release, because I thought this whole confusion has not been there the last time I did this.

So I downloaded this: http://php.net/get/php-5.4.39.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror

It had the `./configure` script.

Now my question: Why are the relases on php.net and the releases on GitHub different?
And how if not with the `./buildconf` script should I obtain a `./configure` script without using `./buildconf` which should obviously not be used in a *release* version?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub contains a mirror of PHP development version. Development versions usually don't have `configure` script, because it has to be regenerated each time any of autotools input files changes. And these files tend to change during development phase.

You may read instructions on how to use development version and `buildconf` script on [php website](http://php.net/git.php).

Release versions for end users, with generated `configure` script, should be downloaded directly from [php.net](http://php.net/downloads.php).

Comment: So if I get this right, the code of a tag or release is not exactly the same as in the release packages on PHP?

Comment: @func0der I think the only difference is that git "releases" don't have autotools generated scripts.